# What is the event name for "Continue Shopping" button or the plug in for the same?

Tags: magento2, shopping

Once the user clicks "continue shopping", I got to take him to a custom page.

Can anyone suggest me a way or extension?

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Can you please tell me where the "continue shopping" button available in your store?

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-thank-you-page/ OR 
https://amasty.com/thank-you-page-for-magento-2.html

Comment: @Ranganathan Continue shopping button is placed after the customer places the order..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override file from

> vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\success.phtml

to

> app\design\frontend\vendor\yourtheme\Magento_Checkout\templates\success.phtml

replace your url for continue shopping button

**Or**

Override block `\Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success`

For url you can return your custom URL from `getContinueUrl()` function. with your conditions.

You can Achieve this using plugin method:

`di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="\Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success">
        <plugin name="custom_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Success" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

`app\code\Vendor\Module\Plugin\Success.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;
class Success
{
    public function afterGetContinueUrl(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success $subject, $result) {
        return "your url";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir...Can you please tell me the block of this template as I have to validation also depending upon the customer who is logged in..

Comment: Then you can override this block `\Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success` only for url and your validation I think. No need to override phtml

Comment: One last thing how do u get the hints instantly i.e "Continue shopping" is present in module-checkout...and that too the correct suuccess.phtml file......I am new to magento..

Comment: You can get the phtml file path by enable configuration from -> `Admin->Store->Configuration->Advanced->Developer->Debug->Enable Template Path Hints for Storefront = yes` flush your cache and you can see the path from frontend.

Comment: ok..........Thanks